# Bernoulli distribution: p and the expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I can't make out a couple of things about the Bernoulli distribution. Help would be greatly appreciated.

200 lottery tickets cost USD 1 each. One of them gives a win of USD 101 (the cost plus 100). The remaining ones give no return (loses a dollar). Let Z denote the net result when purchasing one lottery ticket. Find the probability function for Z and calculate the expected value and the variance.

Clearly, $p_z(-1)=0.995$, and $p_z(101)=0.005$. One of these should represent $p$ in the Bernoulli distribution according to the definition, surely?

Now, the expected value $E(Z)$ is supposed to equal $p$, but it turns out that $E(Z)=-0.495$. How does that happen?

Comment: it should be $p_z(100)=0.005$ if you consider net result. anyways expected value is negative because on average you are making a loss

Comment: You’re confusing yourself with the definitions of winnings when you write $p_z$. In fact, you win $100$ if you win, and not $101$, so it should be $p_z(100)=0.005$. And why do you think $E(Z)=p$? $Z$ is not Bernoulli. In Bernoulli you can only get $0$ or $1$ but here $Z\in \{-1,100\}$.